# JQuery datepicker set manual date not a current date of calender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

How we can set a our manual date not a current date of calender (e.g now date is 2021 but i want to set date of year 2020) into datepicker JQuery??

Answer (score 0):

Simply use setYear Method of Date Object :

```
var NewDate = new Date().setYear(2020);
new Date(NewDate) // Your required Date
// Wed Mar 18 2020 16:58:23
```

Comment: Its not working it get the date 2020 well,, but i want to set a date which is getting from input value that input value date i want to set into a dapicker date and also set the restriction on month and year that just one previous month can be selected otherwise other previous month or year not be selected... ??

Comment: <label class="control-label">Date:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"              placeholder="Select Date" name="valueMonths"   id="valueMonths" readonly="readonly" value="<s:property value="#session.sessionBean.valueDate.toString().split('-')[0]"/>-<s:property value="#session.sessionBean.valueDate.toString().split('-')[1]"/>" />
 This is my input here i am getting date from database and that date i want to set into date picker date and selection start from that date other previous year not selected. input in the split[0] i will get year 2021 and split[1] i will get month 03.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mydate" />

<script>
 var d = new Date();
  d.setFullYear(2020);
$("#mydate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", d);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomDay= new Date('01-01-2020');
var mm = String(randomDay.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = String(randomDay.getFullYear());
var day = String(randomDay.getDay());
var dateSet=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+day;
console.log(dateSet);

Set this 'dateSet' variable in your datepicker 'setDate' like this:

var date=e.target.value;
var yearMonthDay=[]; 
yearMonthDay=date.split('-');
var year = yearMonthDay[0];
var month = yearMonthDay[1]; 
var day = yearMonthDay[2];
$(this).datepicker('setDate',new Date(yearMonthDay[0],yearMonthDay[1],yearMonthDay[2]));
```